# PostgresSQL custom sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

I have a problem with `nextval` function, I have a custom sequence in my DB called `InternalCodes` and when i want to make a insert like this:

```
insert into "Membership"
  ("Name", "Code", "Price", "Caducity", "Status", "Type")
values
  ('asd', nextval("InternalCodes"), 1, 2, true, 0);
```

PostgreSQL returns me the following error:

> org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column does not exist «InternalCodes»

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
test=# create sequence seq_test;
test=# select nextval("seq_test");
ERROR:  column "seq_test" does not exist
LINE 1: select nextval("seq_test");
                       ^
test=# select nextval('seq_test');
nextval 
---------
       1
```

In your case, since your sequence name contains upper case letters, you actually need to use both:

```
insert into "Membership"("Name", "Code", "Price","Caducity","Status","Type") 
values('asd', nextval('"InternalCodes"'), 1,2,true,0)
;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use string quotes:

```
nextval('"InternalCodes"')
```